# Woocommerce Order Reports MYSQL

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I need to create a report system on wordpress for orders and sales. I am using [Exports and Reports](https://wordpress.org/plugins/exports-and-reports/) plugin and it needs to call data from the database with the use of MYSQL.

I have read that woocommerce has encrypted their data ever since 3.0 version? Is there a way to call all the Customer Orders without the use of PHP and just by MYSQL? I would like to learn how. Thanks.

Comment: Where'd you read that? Have you even tried exporting WooCommerce data yet? Why not try to see if there's even an issue.

Comment: WooCommerce Report is good by itself but I need to separate each data and specify them to each report tab and the plugin is byfar the closest I got.

Comment: I meant trying with the plugin. You implied it might not work because the data is supposedly encrypted. As far as I can tell that’s not true. So why not just try using this plugin. Is the data encrypted?

Comment: I can't seem to SELECT the "woocommerce orders" data from the database since I can't find the exact/speicific woocommerce column.

Comment: WooCommerce orders are stored as posts with the `shop_order` post type.